# How to merge two columns with incomplete information?

Tags: mysql

I have the following schema in my MySQL database, where I have read access:

```
table1 (customersid*:int, zip1:int) 

table2 (customersfid*:int, zip2:int)
```

Where `customersid` references some customers and `zip1` and `zip2` corresponds to zip code area of that particular customers . Ideally the tables have similar information. However, in my tables zip code is sometimes incomplete:

`customersfid` is the foreign key of `customersid`:

Minimal Example:

```
       table1                      table2
customersid  zip1          customersfid      zip2
1            1001                 1          1001
2            700                  2          700
3            20                   3          20
4            60                   4          60
5            0                    5          30
6            NULL                 6          10
7            33                   7          NULL
8            25                   8          0
9            55                   9          66
10            0                   10         0
```

I would like to merge them into one column with the following idea (always in favor to `zip1`):

```
customersid  zip1                          customersfid  zip2
1            1001                           1           1001
2            700                            2           700
3            20                             3           20
4            60                             4           60
5            30           <-30              5           30
6            10           <-10              6           10
7            33                             7           NULL
8            25                             8           0
9            55         always keep zip1    9           66
10            0                             10          0
```

Comment: Check your field names. Looks to me that they are not the same everywhere in your question.

Comment: Im sorry...edited! Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can merge them in a SELECT, no problem. Something like:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN t1.zip1 in (NULL, 0) then t2.zip2 ELSE t1.zip1 END merged_zip
FROM table1 t1
  INNER JOIN table2 t2 on t1.customersid = t2.customersfid
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do an upgrade of all rows in `table1` where the `zip1` is 0 (zero) or NULL:

```
update table1 t1
set    zip1=(select zip2 from table2 t2 where t2.customersfid=t1.customersid)
where  zip1 is NULL
or     zip1=0;
```

Comment: Does `update`work with `read` permissons?

Comment: `read` permission on `table2`? Yes this should work. This table is not updated.

Comment: Permission on whole the `database`

Comment: It is years ago that I used MySQL so I do not recall that much about access rights. My guess is that unless you can overwrite the `read` permission of the whole database with an `update` permission on the `table1` you will not be able to execute this update SQL.